Subplugin QGIS Version 3,34
I have a main plugin in QGIS and want to integrate another plugin as a subplugin within it. It should be controlled by a button in the main plugin's menu. How can I do this?

is it really a plugin or just a 2nd window?

It is really plugin

You need to import plugins from utils and then check if it exists:
from qgis.utils import plugins

if plugin_name in plugins:
    print(f"The plugin '{plugin_name}' is available and loaded.")
    my_plugin = plugins[plugin_name]
else:
    print(f"The plugin '{plugin_name}' is not available or not loaded.")
    # Optionally, you can attempt to load the plugin
    if QgsApplication.pluginManager().loadPlugin(plugin_name):
        print(f"The plugin '{plugin_name}' has been loaded successfully.")
        my_plugin = plugins[plugin_name]
    else:
        print(f"Failed to load the plugin '{plugin_name}'.")

and then proceed to use it as you would expect.
